# Is the following statement of swami Sivananda advaitic or non advaitic?

Tags: advaita, guru

Swami Sivananda says in his book [God Exists](https://www.dlshq.org/download/god_exists.htm)

> If we have no faith in God, we will be born again and again in this world and will undergo considerable miseries. The ignorant, faithless, doubting self goes to destruction. He cannot enjoy the least happiness. Neither this world, nor that beyond is there for the doubting self. Those who have no faith in God do not know what is right and what is wrong. They have lost the power of discrimination. They are untruthful, proud and egoistic. They are given to excessive greed, wrath and lust. They hoard up money by unlawful means. They become men of demoniacal nature. They commit various sorts of atrocious crimes. They have no ideals for their lives. They are thrown into the lowest depths, deluded, birth after birth.<sup>(*chapter 2 Why Should We Believe In God*?)</sup>

So is this advaitic because advaita vedanta followes the path of knowledge and not the path of devotion(*bhakti yoga*) . And belief in God is only required for path of devotion and not the path of knowledge(*jnana yoga*)

Comment: People have variously misunderstood Advaita. Advaita is mainly Jnana yogic. But afaik it maintains that to acheove Jnana, Bhakti and Karma is needed. So Bhakti is of great importance. Moreover Advaitis maintain that one can get Jnana only of Ishwara wills so. So also Bhakti is very important. There is a saying in Avadhita Gita, Ishwarasya Anugraahdeva Pumsam Advaita Vasana. That means Humans get the Advaitic tendency only because of God's grace. So the statement of Swami Shivananda is not opposed to Advaita.

Comment: See Gita 6.47 and Gita 17.28

Comment: Yoga (union) can never be achieved unless Jnana, Karma and Bhakti come together irrespective of how it starts. These are like three pods of a tripod. One or two pods cannot stand on their own. Say one forgets himself while eating Mangoes. While enjoying (Bhakti) eating (Karma) it, one is aware (Jnana) of the sweet taste of it. Try removing any of these and the entire experience remains infeasible.

Answer (score 1):

Yoga (Union) is impossible without it being Advaitic. Swami Sivananda is correct from his point of vantage.

Yoga (union) can never be achieved unless Jnana, Karma and Bhakti come together irrespective of how it starts. These are like three pods of a tripod. One or two pods cannot stand on their own.

Say one forgets himself while eating Mangoes. While enjoying (Bhakti) eating (Karma) it, one is aware (Jnana) of the sweet taste of it. Try removing any of these and the entire experience comes apart with no bliss.

Ramana Maharishi says - **the four paths are not mutually exclusive** (page 39).

[The Four Paths: Ramana Maharshi on Bhakti, Jnana, Karma](https://archive.org/details/Acc.No.6193UpadesaSaram1970/page/n19/mode/2up?q=bhakti)
[More on the four paths and their intersection - Pages 38 and 39](https://archive.org/details/Acc.No.6193UpadesaSaram1970/page/n45/mode/2up?q=bhakti)

Ramana Maharishi has this to say in the context of Advaita
(source: [Talks With Sri Ramana Maharishi](https://bookstore.sriramanamaharshi.org/product/talks-with-sri-ramana-maharshi-ebook/) ):

> Talk 35.  An educated visitor asked Bhagavan about dvaita and advaita.
> M.: Identification with the body is ***dvaita***. Non-identification is
> ***advaita***.